# allow special characters in codeigniter (specially designing font of a-z and A-Z)

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I want to insert data using codeigniter query (sql) when designing font insert into my database it looks like ???? in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the change the datatype of column

```
You need to define your columns as nvarchar/nchar if you want unicode data. 
Note, internally SQL Server stores this as UCS-2
```

if mysql then use utf8 for table

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

or on your table column

```
ALTER TABLE <yourtable_name > MODIFY <column_name> VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER 
SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: actually my fonts is like these   ғȏяєıɢṅ ғяıєṅԀṡ

Comment: But in my database type does  not have nvarchar option, I am using MYSQL 5.7.9